# PHP using GLOB to restrict files being read based on file name

Tags: php, regex, filenames

I am trying to use glob() to read files in a directory that contains various file types. I have managed somehow to fetch the once I want which are .txt files using:

```
glob($dir.'*.txt')
```

From the files read I obtain to types of files which server different functionality and have been grouped based on name. Sample of this files are

```
MSPP850_36907816201203161900989.txt
MSPP850_36907816201203161805560.txt
MSP850_36907816201203161805560.txt
MSP850_36907816201203161805560.txt
MSP850_36907816201203161805560.txt
MSP850_36907816201203161805560.txt
```

Note the files name before the underscore: we have two types i.e MSPP850 and MSP850.
How can I use glob to filter and fetch only MSP850 files for instance.

Comment: Please see [glob (programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
glob($dir.'MSP850_*.txt');
```

Comment: I was just about to send same answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfect.Is it a reg-expression?If yes I think I should read it to get the basics. Thanks again.You save my day!

Comment: Its not regex, but `glob()` supports wilcard chars like `*` and `?`.